# PHP - Extend classes using composer autoloader causes redeclare error

Tags: php, inheritance, composer-php, autoloader

I'm just learning how to use composer for my own classes.
So I've this ditectory structure

I'm using PHP version 5.5.30 and Composer 1.1.0

> - Pdf
>
>   - test.php
>   - composer.json
>   - vendor/
>
>     - autoload.php
>     - jarouche/
>
>       - jarouche.php
>       - jarouche2.php

**So, I have**

```
  test.php
  <?php
      require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
      use jarouche\jarouche2;

      $teste = new jarouche2();
      $teste->teste();
   ?>
```

---

```
   jarouche.php

   <?php

       namespace jarouche;

       class jarouche{

           public function teste(){
               echo 'jarouche';
           }

        }
   ?>
```

---

```
  jarouche2.php

   <?php

       namespace jarouche;

       class jarouche2 extends jarouche{

           public function teste(){
               echo 'jarouche2';
           }

        }
   ?>
```

---

```
  composer.json

  {
    ...

          "autoload": {
                        ...
                        "psr-4": {"jarouche\\": "vendor/jarouche"
           }
   }
```

---

```
But, when I run test.php I got this error "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class jarouche\jarouche2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pdf\vendor\jarouche\jarouche2.php on line 6"
```

I've tried putting a `if (!class_exists('MyClass')) in jarouche2.php`, tried to update composer... nothing worked.

What's my mistake?

Comment: `Pdf\vendor\jarouche\jarouche2.php` is not `app\vendor\jarouche\jarouche2.php`

Comment: Thanks for advice.I've fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I did a composer self-update and now it's working!